# Ошибка BadimageFormatException

Tags: c#

При переносе с одного компьютера на другой проекта, при загрузке выскакивает ошибка BadimageFormatException. Прошу помощи[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, друзья

Comment: Либо путь к файлу картинки изменился, либо картинка при переносе проекта потерялась, вот ошибочка и вылезла.

Comment: Я переименовал вышележащие пути...Буду смотреть, спасибо

Comment: Думаю, Image означает не картинку, а образ исполняемого файла. У вас случайно битность системы не поменялась?

Comment: Поменялось, перенес на 64 битку